# Reverse string with pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, reverse

I tried following two ways to reverse a string in C using char pointers:

**Option 1:**

```
void stringreverse(char *s){
    int n = stringlength(s) - 2;

    while(*s != '\0'){
        char c = *s;
        *s = *(s+n);
        *(s+n) = c;
        s++;n--;
    }       
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
void stringreverse(char *s){
    char *p = s + stringlength(s) - 2;

    while(*s != '\0'){
        char c = *s;
        *s = *p;
        *p = c;
        s++,p--;
    }   
}
```

None of the above works. Hints on why?

Comment: Why are you subtracting 2 in `int n = stringlength(s) - 2; `?

Comment: The way it is defined, stringlength("Hello") = 6 (e.g.). So, to point to 'o', which is at index 4, I need to do stringlength("Hello") - 2 = 6 - 2 = 4

Comment: They both try to reverse the string twice. How many swaps does it take to reverse a 13 character string? How many swaps does this code do?

Comment: I assumed it was a re-implementation of [strlen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/).

Comment: You need to exit the loop once `s >= p` (in the second version).  Otherwise you are undoing the previous swaps.  The first version of the loop is just broken, since `(s+n)` never changes (`s` is incremented and `n` is decremented each time through, so the sum is constant).

Comment: @TomKarzes, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your code reverses the string and then reverse it again, because your loop goes from 0 to len (when *s==\0), it should stop at (len-1)/2

You should try this :

```
void stringreverse(char* s){
  int len = strlen(s)-1;
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<len/2;i++){
    char tmp = s[i];
    s[i] = s[len-i];
    s[len-i]=tmp;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To reverse the string you should swap the chars between the beginning and the end of the string until they meet in the middle, the way you did will reverse it and then reverse it again to the original string. Also there is `strlen` in standard C. Anyway using your definition of `stringlength`, it should be:

```
void stringreverse(char *s){
    int n = stringlength(s) - 2;
    int i;
    while(i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n-i];
        s[n-i] = c;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

complete working sample using pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
void reverse(char *p){
    char c;
    char* q = p;
    while (*q) q++;
    q--; // point to the end
    while (p < q){
        c = *p;
        *p++ = *q;
        *q-- = c;
    }
}

int main(){
    char s[] = "DCBA";
    reverse(s);
    printf("%s\n", s); // ABCD
}
```

p: points to start of string.
q: points to the end of string.
then swap their contents.
simple and easy.